# Passing data from parent to child component (MaterialUI make styles)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm quite new to reactjs and I'm working on a simple page that uses authentication using state. Also, for styling I'm using MaterialUI framework.

I'm trying to send the **loggedInStatus** prop.

I think I'm sending the props correctly, but I think that I'm messing my code with receiving the props... :S

My App.js is as follows:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './components/layout/Navbar';
import Home from './components/home/Home';
import SignIn from './components/auth/SignIn';
import Contacto from './components/contacto/Contacto'
import FamCatalog from './components/famCatalog/FamCatalog'
import ProtectedRoute from './components/protected/ProtectedRoute'
import PageError from './components/404/PageError';
class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      loggedInStatus: 'NOT_LOGGED_IN',
      user: {}
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
          <Navbar />
          <Switch>
            <Route
              exact
              path='/'
              render={props => (
                <Home {...props} loggedInStatus={this.state.loggedInStatus} />
              )}
            />
            <Route path='/signin' component={SignIn} />
            <ProtectedRoute path='/famcatalog' component={FamCatalog} />
            <Route path='/contacto' component={Contacto} />
            <Route path='*' component={PageError} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Then, the child component is as follows:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import cloudComputing from '../../img/cloud-computing.png';
import dashboard from '../../img/dashboard.png';
import data from '../../img/data.png';
import dataSearch from '../../img/dataSearch.png';
import webDevelop from '../../img/web-development.png';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    width: '100%',
    maxWidth: '75%',
    marginLeft: 'auto',
    marginRight: 'auto',
  },
  texto: {
    padding: 10,

  },
  imagenes: {
    padding: 50,
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'space-evenly'
  }
});

function Nested() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className={classes.root} >
      <h1>Status: {this.props.loggedInStatus}</h1>
      <div className={classes.imagenes}>
        <img src={webDevelop} alt='' />
        <img src={cloudComputing} alt='' />
        <img src={dashboard} alt='' />
        <img src={data} alt='' />
        <img src={dataSearch} alt='' />
      </div>

      <Typography variant="h3" gutterBottom align='center'>
        ...Blah, Blah, Blah...
      </Typography>

      <Typography variant="subtitle1" gutterBottom className={classes.texto} align='justify'>
        ...Blah, Blah, Blah...
      </Typography>

    </div >
  )
}

class Home extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  
  render() {
    return <Nested />
  }
}

export default Home;
```

I can't get the props. I still have the error: "**TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined**" and also have a warning saying **Useless constructor** for the constructor created inside **Home** class.

I'm trying to implement the workflow explained in: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zSt5G3s3OJI inside my code. As I didn't have a class component, I needed to re-arranged my **Home** component to satisfy the class component following the guidelines in (maybe here is the error...):

https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/

Any tip of advice in what I'm doing wrong will be very well received!

Thanks in advance!

#### EDIT

In order to responder @HermitCrab, my new Home.js component:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import cloudComputing from '../../img/cloud-computing.png';
import dashboard from '../../img/dashboard.png';
import data from '../../img/data.png';
import dataSearch from '../../img/dataSearch.png';
import webDevelop from '../../img/web-development.png';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    width: '100%',
    maxWidth: '75%',
    marginLeft: 'auto',
    marginRight: 'auto',
  },
  texto: {
    padding: 10,

  },
  imagenes: {
    padding: 50,
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'space-evenly'
  }
});

class Home extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  function Nested() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
      <div className={classes.root} >
        {/* <h1>Status: {this.props.loggedInStatus}</h1> */}
        <div className={classes.imagenes}>
          <img src={webDevelop} alt='' />
          <img src={cloudComputing} alt='' />
          <img src={dashboard} alt='' />
          <img src={data} alt='' />
          <img src={dataSearch} alt='' />
        </div>
  
        <Typography variant="h3" gutterBottom align='center'>
          ... some text ...
        </Typography>
  
        <Typography variant="subtitle1" gutterBottom className={classes.texto} align='justify'>
         ... some text ...
        </Typography>
  
      </div >
    )
  }

  render() {
    return <Nested />
  }
}

export default Home;
```

And I'm getting this error: [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJUw3.png)

thanks in advance!

#### EDIT #2

I'm trying a couple of things. Here is a way I introduced the function content into the Home Component:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import cloudComputing from '../../img/cloud-computing.png';
import dashboard from '../../img/dashboard.png';
import data from '../../img/data.png';
import dataSearch from '../../img/dataSearch.png';
import webDevelop from '../../img/web-development.png';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    width: '100%',
    maxWidth: '75%',
    marginLeft: 'auto',
    marginRight: 'auto',
  },
  texto: {
    padding: 10,

  },
  imagenes: {
    padding: 50,
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'space-evenly'
  }
});

class Home extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {

    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
      <div className={classes.root} >
        {/* <h1>Status: {this.props.loggedInStatus}</h1> */}
        <div className={classes.imagenes}>
          <img src={webDevelop} alt='' />
          <img src={cloudComputing} alt='' />
          <img src={dashboard} alt='' />
          <img src={data} alt='' />
          <img src={dataSearch} alt='' />
        </div>

        <Typography variant="h3" gutterBottom align='center'>
          ... TEXT
        </Typography>

        <Typography variant="subtitle1" gutterBottom className={classes.texto} align='justify'>
         ... TEXT
        </Typography>

      </div >
    )
  }
}

export default Home;
```

In the local:3000 I'm getting the following error:

[error in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ABBf.png)

I'm quite lost here. How do I include the nested function inside the Home class to get the props?

Any tip of advice will be very well received.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Edit additional information into your question description, please do not use the answer box for this!

Comment: Thanks Emile. I'm new to StackOverflow and couldn't get how to put a snippet into the Comment area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `Nested` is outside of your `Home` component, therefore `this` is undefined and you can't access `this.props`. You have to move your Nested function inside your Home component if you want to be able to access the props passed to Home

Comment: Below, I posted you thew snippet including the function insode the Home component, but no results.. What am I missing here?. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Replace `function Nested()`   with   `Nested = () =>`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I Managed to work with your recommendations! But finally I changed my component to a functional component and it worked perfecto for what I was looking for.

Comment: Kudos to you for moving to functional components, that's the way to go :)

Comment: Thanks! I'll be consulting this forum to seek for knowledge =)!